# how can i retrive the attributes which influence the result in a dataset in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, feature-selection

I am a beginner. I am doing gpa prediction. My dataset have variables like travel time of the student,study time , parents occupation , their grades,mother occupation etc.how can i retrieve the attributes which influence the gpa of the student? My data has both categorical and discrete values.

Comment: this may help you . https://machinelearningmastery.com/an-introduction-to-feature-selection/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RandomForestRegressor` in python on your train data to fit a model. Then you can use `feature_importance_` function to find the importance of each feature. And if you are interested in explanatory power of your model then you can also use the function `treeinterpreter` from the package `treeinterpreter`. Here are two links([link1](http://blog.datadive.net/interpreting-random-forests/), [link2](http://blog.datadive.net/random-forest-interpretation-with-scikit-learn/)) that give more insight on treeinterpreter.

Answer (score -1):

According to what I understand from your question, you want to know which features have more influence over the final GPA of a student, is that correct? If it is the case, some machine learning algorithms have this built-in function which gives you the feature importance of each feature (coefficients) used in the model. For example, if you are using Logistic Regression, it has a function called `coef_`, this will result all the coefficients of the features used. More information about `coef_` can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Another algorithm which has this built-in function is the Random Forest. This algorithms contains a function called `feature_importance_` which produce an array of size n_features. In general, the feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature). More information about `feature_importance_` function can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).